# Want to take a difference of dates

Tags: sql, oracle

In my query I want to take a difference of two dates.

```
(SELECT
        (SELECT estimated_arrival AS val2
        FROM shipment_stop
        WHERE stop_num =5
        AND shipment_gid ='IFFCO/LOGISTICS.LG171009102'
        ) -
        (SELECT estimated_arrival AS val1
        FROM shipment_stop
        WHERE stop_num   = 1
        AND shipment_gid = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.LG171009102'
        )
        FROM dual
        )
```

so basically suppose Val1 is having 10-Oct-2017 and Val2 is having 13-Oct-2017 so if I am doing Val2 - Val1 then it should show 3 Days but it is showing as 3.237856747474747474, looks like it is using the time also. Is there a way to handle this?
Note: Estimated_arrival is date column

Comment: use [trunc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) for eliminate time

Comment: format the date to the desired format and then TO_DATE(val2)-TO_DATE(val1)

Comment: This kind of depends on what you're trying to show. If `VAL1` is `10-OCT-2017` and `VAL2` is `13-OCT-2017`, then the difference between the dates is 3 days, as you say - but if you're trying to determine how long it took to make all the stops it took FOUR days (10-OCT, 11-OCT, 12-OCT, and 13-OCT).

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times. It just wastes everybody's time. Two people had already taken the trouble to answer your question the first time you asked it. If you didn't get the answer you wanted you should have engaged with those responders instead of posting the same question again.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use to remove the time component.  It is unclear whether you want to do this before or after the subtraction.  Basically, do you consider 11:00 a.m. on one day to be 0 days or 1 day from 10:00 a.m. on the following day?

I'm guessing you want 1 day in this case.  If so, use `trunc()` *before* subtracting:

```
SELECT ( (SELECT trunc(estimated_arrival) AS val2
          FROM shipment_stop
          WHERE stop_num = 5 AND shipment_gid = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.LG171009102'
         ) -
         (SELECT trunc(estimated_arrival) AS val1
          FROM shipment_stop
          WHERE stop_num   = 1 AND shipment_gid = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.LG171009102'
         )
       ) as diff_days
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions to use `trunc()` to set the time part of the DATE column to midnight (00:00:00), you don't need to have two select statements to work the difference out.

E.g. assuming that shipment_gid and stop_num are unique, you could do something like:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN stop_num = 5 THEN TRUNC(estimated_arrival) END)
         - MAX(CASE WHEN stop_num = 1 THEN TRUNC(estimated_arrival) END) date_difference
FROM   shipment_stop
WHERE  stop_num IN (1, 5)
AND    shipment_gid = 'IFFCO/LOGISTICS.LG171009102';
```